# Pandas DataFrame - Compute frequency of number w/ a greater value before current date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to count the frequency of the number of occurrences a value has been higher than today's value for all dates in the past.

I've looked into using pandas [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) and [cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) functions, but still cannot figure out how to do this efficiently.

Below is a working code snippet of what I'm trying to achieve with the output displayed in the image following. My gut says that this is an extremely ugly and inefficient approach, so I was hoping to find something better.

```py
    def freq_greater_than(r):
        smaller_date = df[df.date < r.date]
        larger_num = smaller_date[(smaller_date.num > r.num)]
        return round(len(larger_num) / len(smaller_date) * 100, 2)
    
    index = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-01-10')
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict(num=np.random.random_integers(0, 100, len(index))), index=pd.Series(index, name='date'))
    df['date'] = df.index
    df['freq_greater_than'] = df.iloc[1:].apply(freq_greater_than, axis=1)
    df.style.format({'freq_greater_than': '{:.2f}%'})
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of data, it doesn't help, you need to post data in a format that we can copy/paste. See this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: @joao, data is already there in the copy/paste format, that image represents the expected outcome.

Comment: oh, my bad, I didn't see you were generating random data

Comment: @joao, it's not me, it's OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [`expanding apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.expanding.Expanding.apply.html#pandas-core-window-expanding-expanding-apply) + [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mean.html#pandas-series-mean) over [`gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html#pandas-series-gt) comparison:

```
df['freq_greater_than'] = (
    df['num'].expanding()
        .apply(lambda s: s.iloc[:-1].gt(s.iloc[-1]).mean() * 100)
)
```

`df`:

```
            num       date  freq_greater_than
date                                         
2020-01-01   72 2020-01-01                NaN
2020-01-02   28 2020-01-02         100.000000
2020-01-03   47 2020-01-03          50.000000
2020-01-04    2 2020-01-04         100.000000
2020-01-05   73 2020-01-05           0.000000
2020-01-06    8 2020-01-06          80.000000
2020-01-07   87 2020-01-07           0.000000
2020-01-08   94 2020-01-08           0.000000
2020-01-09   40 2020-01-09          62.500000
2020-01-10   25 2020-01-10          77.777778
```

Optional [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas-series-map) for string formatting:

```
df['freq_greater_than'] = (
    df['num'].expanding()
        .apply(lambda s: s.iloc[:-1].gt(s.iloc[-1]).mean() * 100)
        .map('{:.2f}%'.format)
)
```

```
            num       date freq_greater_than
date                                        
2020-01-01   72 2020-01-01              nan%
2020-01-02   28 2020-01-02           100.00%
2020-01-03   47 2020-01-03            50.00%
2020-01-04    2 2020-01-04           100.00%
2020-01-05   73 2020-01-05             0.00%
2020-01-06    8 2020-01-06            80.00%
2020-01-07   87 2020-01-07             0.00%
2020-01-08   94 2020-01-08             0.00%
2020-01-09   40 2020-01-09            62.50%
2020-01-10   25 2020-01-10            77.78%
```

---

DataFrame Constructor and Imports:

```
import pandas as pd

index = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-01-10')
df = pd.DataFrame({'num': [72, 28, 47, 2, 73, 8, 87, 94, 40, 25]},
                  index=pd.Series(index, name='date'))
df['date'] = df.index
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.expanding()`:

```py
# convert date and sort dataframe:
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df = df.sort_values(by="date")

df["freq_greater_than"] = (
    df["num"]
    .expanding(1)
    .apply(lambda x: ((x.iat[-1] < x[:-1]).sum() / (len(x) - 1)) * 100)
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        date  num  freq_greater_than
0 2020-01-01   72                NaN
1 2020-01-02   28              100.0
2 2020-01-03   47               50.0
3 2020-01-04    2              100.0
4 2020-01-05   73                0.0
5 2020-01-06    8               80.0

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way with `expanding`:

```
df["freq_gt"] = (df.num
                   .expanding()
                   .agg(lambda x: 100 * x.iloc[:-1].gt(x.iat[-1]).sum() / (x.size - 1)))
```

where `expanding` sends ever-increasing windows over `num` column and `x` represents the windows. Then we look at the values except for the last one via `iloc[:-1]` and compare it (`gt`) with the last one (`iat[-1]`). Then `sum` counts the number of `True`s resulted from comparison which gives the count of those that are greater. Dividing it by the window size minus 1 to exclude the current value and `100 *`  gives the ratio,

to get

```
            num     freq_gt
date
2020-01-01   46         NaN
2020-01-02   35  100.000000
2020-01-03   80    0.000000
2020-01-04    4  100.000000
2020-01-05   43   50.000000
2020-01-06    4   80.000000
2020-01-07    7   66.666667
2020-01-08   91    0.000000
2020-01-09   95    0.000000
2020-01-10   99    0.000000
```